# XML to Dictionary Conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, json

I am new in IOS - Objective c and XML data Parsing as well. Using ABBEY scanner i am getting a XML and using "XMLReader" (downloaded from Github) and getting the dictionary value like this,

```
    xmlDictionary = {
    items = {
        item = {
            id = 0001;
            type = donut;
            name = {
                text = Cake;
            };
            ppu = {
                text = 0.55;
            };
            batters = {
                batter = (
                    {
                        id = 1001;
                        text = Regular;
                    },
                    {
                        id = 1002;
                        text = Chocolate;
                    },
                    {
                        id = 1003;
                        text = Blueberry;
                    }
                );
            };
            topping = (
                {
                    id = 5001;
                    text = None;
                },
                {
                    id = 5002;
                    text = Glazed;
                },
                {
                    id = 5005;
                    text = Sugar;
                }
            );
        };
     };
 }
```

How can i parse this kind of dictionary, showing value null for all aspect. Please help

Comment: What key you have to fetch this Dictionary ? use NSJSONSerialization for parse the data

Comment: I do not understand the question "showing value null for all aspect".

Comment: @SureshThoutam JSON-Serializer for XML?